# Pen won't sculpt in blender

Tags: sculpting, hardware

I've just started using blender. At first, my XP PEN was able to sculpt just fine using its pen. Now, however, the pen suddenly doesn't work when sculpting. The tablet recognizes the pen is there, as the mouse follows it. I am also still able to select buttons using the pen. I cannot, however, sculpt. When I use my mouse, I can sculpt just fine. Simply the pen will not work. I do not believe I altered any settings.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: This looks more like a hardware configuration issue at the operating system level, preferences or driver.

Comment: Are you using rechargeable pen? Is it recharged? Have you installed the tablet driver?

Comment: Yes my pen is charged and functional in every aspect -- other than sculpting. For some reason it won't sculpt, but it can click on buttons just fine. I do have the latest driver. I'm very confused as to what is wrong.